# Mutal exclusion and disable the interupts

Tags: interrupt, critical-region

Hello guys i have question
When a process is entering the critical region one way to stop other processes to enter the same critical region is to disable the interupts
My problem is:
Ok we disable the interrupts so the hardware can no longer stop this procces but if the sceduler says "ok i am stopping you so i can run another procces" and this new process enters the same critical region then we have a problem because this procces is going to enter the same critical region.What happens when this happens?
Thank you!

Comment: How can the scheduler run another process when the scheduler is only entered after a timer interrupt, and you have disabled interrupts? (I’m assuming a single core CPU). But anyway you answered your own question by using the term Mutual exclusion (mutex). Go look at mutex in your RTOS documentation.

Comment: Thanks you answer it